# How to print preview a hidden sheet, keeping sheet hidden?

Tags: excel, vba

How can I convert this sub to print preview Sheet3, that's hidden, while keeping it hidden?

```
Sub PrintPreview()
Sheet3.PrintOut preview:=True

End Sub
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Unhide, print preview, re-hide?

Comment: I tried finding something along the lines but nothing that's sheet specific, anything is appreciated if you can help :)

Comment: :) Heyo, thanks BigBen

Answer (score 1):

```
Sheet3.Visible = True
Sheet3.PrintOut preview:=True
Sheet3.Visible = False
```

@BigBen, thanks for the assist

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
Sub PrintPreview()
    With Sheet3
        .Visible = xlSheetVisible
        '.PrintPreview
        .PrintOut preview:=True
        .Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    End With

End Sub
```